# Increment a year until all digits are odd (closest odd date to original date)

Tags: java, date, if-statement, while-loop

My program requires that I take in a year (E.g. 2020) and check that every number in the year is odd(has only 3, 5, 7, 9). if every number in the year is not odd, then I need to calculate the closest date to the original that has all odd digits. in order to do this I have coded an if statement that checks if the last digit is odd and then checks all the others, if they are even then it increments. However, i am having an issue where the last two digits in a date aren't correct. for example it will output correctly if i input 1900 or 1600 or 1570 - the nearest odd date will be 1911 and 1711 and 1571 respectively. however, if i enter a date where last two digits aren't zero then the output is wrong (E.g. 2020's output should be 3111 but it instead output 3131). I have been going back and forth on how to change this but it only results in more errors. if anyone could help fix this code or provide some logic of how to go about fixing it that would be great.

```
// Increment the last digit of the year to make it odd
                if (year % 10 % 2 == 0) {
                    year++;
                    System.out.println("year after increment:" + year);
                }
// check all other digits and increment
                int temp = year / 10;
                int i = 10;
                while (temp > 0) {
                    if (temp % i % 2 == 0) {
                        year += i;
                    }
                    i *= 10;
                    temp /= 10;
                }
                System.out.println("Year:" + year);
```

I tried:
2020
1900
1570
1620
3461

I expected an output of:
3111
1911
1571
1711
3511

What i got:
3131
1911
1571
1731
3571

Comment: You are only handling each digit once due to the nature of your while loop. I imagine that you want to have the bottom two lines of your while loop in and `else{}` statement, but even then, I don't believe you will see the result you expect.

Comment: It seems pretty clear that your code turns 2020 into 3131 since you are only considering incrementing each digit individually. You wanted 3111, but there is nothing in your code that would turn the 2 in the 10ths place into a 1. An idea would be to start from the most significant digit and whenever one digit is incremented, you can just replace every less significant digit with 1 regardless what it was.

Comment: You wrote: _if i input ... 1600 ... the nearest odd date will be ... 1711_ Actually I think it will be 1599.

Comment: *calculate the closest date to the original that has all odd digits* Did you mean the closest *later* year?

Comment: @Abra It’s not perfectly clear, but I interpret the word *increment* in the title to mean the next *higher* year value (so not 1599). I’d prefer it this had been clear from the body of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everyone who needs it here’s the answer:

```
boolean allOdd = true;
String yearString = Integer.toString(year);
for (char digit : yearString.toCharArray()) {
    int num = Character.getNumericValue(digit);
    if (num % 2 == 0) {
        allOdd = false;
        break;
    }
}

if (!allOdd) {
    int increment = 1;
    while (true) {
        int newYear = year + increment;
        String newYearString = Integer.toString(newYear);
        boolean newAllOdd = true;
        for (char digit : newYearString.toCharArray()) {
            int num = Character.getNumericValue(digit);
            if (num % 2 == 0) {
                newAllOdd = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (newAllOdd) {
            year = newYear;
            break;
        }
        increment += 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution. I cannot understand how your code was supposed to work exactly, even though it does seem to have some right ideas in it. Also answers work best with some explanation You may edit your answer and add some. Finally for year 3105 your program doesn’t seem to stop. I suspect that it may be running in an infinite loop. Same for year 2023.

Comment: The OP's method will fail for `2021,1901,1627,1253` and apparently any year where the least significant digit is odd and any other is even.  This is probably because the increment changes to 2 and skips over valid solutions, causing an infinite loop. I believe changing the increment to `increment += 1`  solves the problem but I did not thoroughly test it.

Comment: In analyzing your answer (and getting an idea which I added to my answer), if you simply do `year += (year % 2 == 1) ? 0 : 1;`  as the first statement  in the `if (!allOdd) {` conditional, you can keep the year odd if it is odd or add `1` to make it odd.  Then increment year by `2` later on.  I believe this was your original intention.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to your problem (In JavaScript, although the algorithm will work for you)

```js
function getOddYear (year) {

    // convert to string
    const yearString = year.toString();
    
    // initialize an empty string to be used to store transformedYearDigits
    let modYearString = '';
    
    // a boolean to check if any of the digits has been transformed already
    let transformedOneAlready = false;

    // loop over each of the digits
    for (let index = 0; index < yearString.length; index++) {
        
        // check if current digit is even
        if (yearString[index] % 2 === 0 && !transformedOneAlready) {    
            modYearString = modYearString.concat(
                parseInt(yearString[index]) + 1
            )
            transformedOneAlready = true;    
        }
        // if transformations has occured: replace the consequent digits with 1(lowest odd number)
        else if (transformedOneAlready){
            modYearString = modYearString.concat(1)
        }
        // if the digit is already odd and no transformation has occured
        else {
            modYearString = modYearString.concat(yearString[index])
        }
    };

    // print the comparison of input and output
    console.log(year, ' --> ',modYearString)
    // convert the transformed year to a number from string
    return parseInt(modYearString);
}


// run the function for each of the numbers in the array
[2020,1911,2034,2344,3241,3048,3035,3481].forEach(
    (e)=>getOddYear(e)
)
```

All you have to do is

1. find the leftmost even digit
2. increment it with 1
3. replace all the consequent digits with the lowest odd number i.e. 1
4. keep the consequent digits as is, if no even number is found

Comment: That’s not Java. Java was used in the question, and the question was tagged java, which means a Java solution was asked for.

Comment: *replace all the consequent even digits with lowest odd number i.e. 1* Correction: replace all the consequent digits no matter if even or odd with lowest odd number i.e. 1. This is also what your code does.

Answer (score 0):

> Increment a year until all digits are odd (closest odd date to original date)

Here is one approach.

```
int[] s = {
        2020,1900,1570,1620,3461
};
for (int year : s) {
    System.out.printf("year = %4d, closest = %4d%n", year,
            closestOddYear(year));
}
```

prints

```
year = 2020, closest = 3111
year = 1900, closest = 1911
year = 1570, closest = 1571
year = 1620, closest = 1711
year = 3461, closest = 3511
```

Starting with the initial year, the method normalizes the year to the first odd one that is equal to or greater the argument.  Subsequent years are increased by 2, skipping the even years since the first low order digit must be odd regardless of the others. This method simply iterates over the odd years until the one meeting the requirements is found.

```
public static int closestOddYear(int year) {
    year += ((year & 1) == 1) ? 0 : 1;
    while (!areDigitsOdd(year)) {
            year += 2;
    }
    return year;
}
```

This method just checks the `lsb` of each exposed digit to see if it is odd.  Since all odd numbers have the lower order bit set, this just ANDs 1 with that bit.  A result of `0` would indicate an even digit, and `1` would be odd. The method short circuits to `false` if any encountered digit is even.  Otherwise it returns `true`.

```
public static boolean areDigitsOdd(int year) {
    while (year > 0) {
        if ((year & 1) != 1) {
            return false;
        }
        year /= 10;
    }
    return true;
}
```